# Sort array of strings with leading numbers followed by non-numeric characters

Tags: php, sorting, natural-sort

I can get a sorted filename list with the following code:

```
$log_files = scandir(LLP_LOG_DIR);
$sorted = sort($log_files);
```

the filename format is X.log, where X is a progressive numeric value.

How can I solve the problem of getting

```
0.log
1.log
10.log
11.log
2.log
3.log
```

where the wanted result is

```
0.log
1.log
2.log
3.log
[..]
9.log
10.log
11.log
[..]
```

I can strip the ".log" string, sort them etc, but what is the most efficient way?

Comment: php has a nice page comparing the sort functions. Read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try natsort instead,

```
natsort($log_files)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the second parameter of [`sort`](http://php.net/sort) to `SORT_NUMERIC` to have numeric sorting:

```
$sorted = $log_files;
sort($sorted, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

And note that `sort` sorts the array of the variable given with the first parameter. The return value of `sort` is just a *boolean* value.

Answer (score 0):

Try natcasesort instead.

```
natcasesort($array);
```

because natsort is case sensitive.